# resize windows 10 system reserved partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning

My **Windows 10** installation uses **System Reserved** partition which is 100 MB (this comes to all of us, after upgrade from Windows 7).

In **Windows 10** the **System Reserved** partition needs to be 450 MB at least.

Windows disk management, does not allow me changing that, cause I have my system partition just next to System reserved partition.

In this case I am unable to extend this partition using basic windows tools.

So how can I safely extend my System reserved partition beyond 100 MB to comply with Windows 10 requirements?

Comment: "In Windows 10 the System Reserved partition needs to be 450 MB at least." - This isn't a requirement.  While the default size is indeed 450 MB, if you were to install Windows 10 on a new storage device, it isn't a requirement for Windows 10 to function.  "So how can I safely extend my System reserved partition beyond 100 MB to comply with Windows 10 requirements?" - Due to the layout of your disk you will be unable to extend the partition in question.

Comment: This will be a complex, multi-step operation. You will need to make space on the drive if there's isn't space already. Then you will need to move the System partition to the end of the available space (clearing space and shrinking automatically shrinks the END of the partition). Then you will need to expand the System Reserved partition. The real question is: Do you need to do this, and the answer is "no". Windows 10 does not actually need 450MB, or whatever they say they need. So, the second question is: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Bart Do you have GPT partition table in HDD? There is no requirement of that. See this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions).

Comment: @music2myear you are right, and in the end I didn't need that. Explanation in answer.

Comment: @Biswa yes I have GPT on this hdd

Comment: If you have GPT what were you trying to change your partition scheme to exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using **gparted** for resizing and moving partitions.
After that I used **Macrium Reflect** to solve Windows boot problems.

So these 2 steps although time consuming solved my original question.
Both programs are absolutely free, as for now, if anybody would ask.

However, I was trying to change my partition scheme, cause windows 10 update 1709 aka Fall Creators Update was failing without any errors unfortunately.
This is now solved in [windows Fall creators update 1709 boot up freeze](https://superuser.com/questions/1264283/windows-fall-creators-update-1709-boot-up-freeze/1264290#1264290)

Comment: We cannot answer questions asked in an answer so you should remove them (they won’t be answered).

Comment: Glad you were able to think your way through to a good solution. RE your follow-up question: Ramhound is right, and as it is currently written that new question is broad. You may need to narrow it with further evidence and information before we'll be able to get you an answer. But, get your info together and post a new question (well, search first, there may already be an answer).

Comment: Done it. Thanks for consideration and remarks...

Comment: That answer exactly solved my problem, thanx dude.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to grow the system reserved partition using the [Minitool partition wizard (v 12.7 free edition)](https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/partition-wizard-home.html). It boots into its own environment in order to make the changes to system partitions. There were no boot problems to correct.

By the way, I had to do this in order to be able to upgrade to Windows 10. The SRP was almost full.